# Passing values through functions

Tags: function, visual-c++, c++-cli, readprocessmemory

I'm trying to create my own functions for ReadProcessMemory and WriteProcessMemory in VisualC++ so I don't have to keep inputting all the info for every time I create a new function call. This project is Windows Form. Here's the problem

```
void Read(DWORD Add, int Value);

private: System::Void btnP1Money_Click_1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^e) 
{   
int BigMoney = 100000;
int GetMoneyValue;
DWORD MonAddr = 0x180A6C8;

Read(MonAddr, GetMoneyValue);
}


void Read(DWORD Add, int Value)
{
HWND window = FindWindow(0, _T("Process Window Name"));
DWORD pID = NULL;
DWORD base = dwGetModuleBaseAddress(pID, _T("Game.exe"));
HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);
GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, &pID);

ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPCVOID)(base+Add), &Value, 4, NULL);
}
```

The value in game is 500, yet the value returned from Read() is 0. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I just don't want to have to define everything in my Read() function everytime on each button click and checkbox tick ect.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the `Read` header to

```
void Read(DWORD Add, int& Value)
```

I've written small example which works. Make sure that you check the content of the variable, not it's address

```
void Read(int& Value)
{
    Value++;
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    int GetMoneyValue = 5;
    Read(GetMoneyValue);

    Console::WriteLine(GetMoneyValue);
    //6;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Vlad. That's exactly what I did to the headers. I changed the function declare to void Read(DWORD Add, int& Value); and the header on the function definition to void Read(DWORD Add, int& Value) { //same code } and it's producing those weird results. Any ideas why?  Thanks

Comment: From WinBase.h   `BOOL WINAPI ReadProcessMemory(
    __in      HANDLE hProcess,
    __in      LPCVOID lpBaseAddress,
    __out_bcount_part(nSize, *lpNumberOfBytesRead) LPVOID lpBuffer,
    __in      SIZE_T nSize,
    __out_opt SIZE_T * lpNumberOfBytesRead
    );`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass by reference, otherwise the function gets its own copy of the `int`:

```
void Read(DWORD Add, int& Value);
```

Alternatively, you could return the value:

```
int Read(DWORD Add, int Value)
{
  ....
  return Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yea I tried to return the value before, but I kept getting 0. I'm trying to do by reference, but it's producing some weird results. I did the void Read(DWORD Add, int& Value); and void Read(DWORD Add, int& Value)
{...} but it produces the output of 1752315632 on first button click and 44293792 on second button click ect.. They're not random so I think I might be passing them wrong.  I've read up on passing values by reference, but this is my first time trying it.